# Отобразить в таблице основной модели ячейку со значениями из другой модели

Tags: python, django

у меня есть модель продукта:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    code = models.IntegerField('Код', unique=True)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    article = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Товар"
        verbose_name_plural = "Товары"
```

Модель коэффициентов на товар в зависимости от пользователя:

```
class ProductsInstance(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                      help_text="Unique ID")
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    coeff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    price_for_client = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="0.00")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} ({1})'.format(self.id, self.product.name)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Коэффициент на товар "
        verbose_name_plural = "Коэффициенты на товары" 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price_for_client = self.product.price * self.coeff 
        super(ProductsInstance, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

выглядит вот так [image: выглядит вот так]

Созданная таблица:

```
class ProductsTable(tables.Table):
    price_for = tables.Column(accessor="product", verbose_name="Цена для клиента")
    class Meta:
        model = Products
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields = ("name","code","article","quantity","price", 'price_for') 
        export_formats = ('xlsx')
```

и вывод этой таблицы:

```
class GoodsSetTable(ExportMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Products
    table_class = ProductsTable
    template_name = 'goods/book_list_table.html' 
    filterset_class = PersonFilter    
    table_pagination = {
        "per_page": 2
    }
```

[image: выглядит вот так]

Мне необходимо, чтобы в колонке "Цена для клиента" отображалась цена из модели ProductsInstance отфильтрованная по поле borrower. Т.е. для меня как для Admin, цена в колонке "Цена для клиента" должна показываться 51000 для Тестового товара. Вопрос, как это реализовать?